# I need a api endpoint to get the logs of a pod and parameters that needs to be passed to that endpoint in openshift

Tags: openshift

i have tried this endpoint-------->https://url/api/v1/namespace/pods/podname/log with bearer token (that i got from login command in OpenShift )in postman but it is returning 404 error

I need run time logs of a given pod

if there is a way to fetch the above data with python it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL may be wrong. You should use `namespaces/<namespace>` instead of `namespace`.
The correct URL is `https://<api-server>:<port>/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace>/pods/<podname>/log`.

You can confirm the URL with the oc command as follows:

```
$ oc logs <pod name> --log-level=9 | head -n 10

...
I1130 15:44:32.942895  709912 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://api.ocp4.example.com:6443/api/v1/namespaces/sample/pods/httpd-97d7658c5-g4z5j/log?container=httpd 200 OK in 18 milliseconds
...
```

Comment: Did your issue solve?

Comment: yes issue solved